# Remove rows where date doesn't fall into any date ranges

Tags: python, date, pandas

So I have a 2 column data frame `datetime` and `value` and I want to remove all rows which do not fall into at least one date range.

E.g. Lets say my valid date ranges are represented as tuples

```
valid_date_ranges = [
                        (2017-01-01 00:00:00.00, 2017-01-03 15:00:00.00),
                        (2017-01-04 03:25:00.00, 2017-01-06 22:56:00.00),
                        ...
                    ]
```

and I have a data frame as such

```
datetime                value
2017-01-01 00:00:00.00  1234
2017-01-01 00:01:00.00  13241526
2017-01-01 10:02:00.00  356356
2017-01-01 10:03:00.00  17435
2017-01-01 10:04:00.00  5234515
2017-01-01 10:05:00.00  52452435
...
2017-01-03 14:59:00.00  156256
2017-01-03 15:00:00.00  665654
2017-01-03 15:01:00.00  890656      *
2017-01-03 15:02:00.00  698765      *
2017-01-03 15:03:00.00  6574        *
...
2017-01-04 03:23:00.00  6541632     *
2017-01-04 03:24:00.00  1234        *
2017-01-04 03:25:00.00  4657347
2017-01-04 03:26:00.00  765
2017-01-04 03:27:00.00  870089
...
```

I want to remove the rows with stars at the end as they don't fall into any of date ranges.

Comment: It looks like `2017-01-04 03:24:00.00  1234` should also be a starred row, based on the exclusion ranges you've specified.

Comment: @andrew_reece edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
# sample df and ranges to exclude, per OP
datetime                value
"2017-01-01 00:00:00.00"  1234
"2017-01-01 00:01:00.00"  13241526
"2017-01-01 10:02:00.00"  356356
"2017-01-01 10:03:00.00"  17435
"2017-01-01 10:04:00.00"  5234515
"2017-01-01 10:05:00.00"  52452435
"2017-01-03 14:59:00.00"  156256
"2017-01-03 15:00:00.00"  665654
"2017-01-03 15:01:00.00"  890656      
"2017-01-03 15:02:00.00"  698765      
"2017-01-03 15:03:00.00"  6574    
"2017-01-04 03:23:00.00"  6541632     
"2017-01-04 03:24:00.00"  1234
"2017-01-04 03:25:00.00"  4657347
"2017-01-04 03:26:00.00"  765
"2017-01-04 03:27:00.00"  870089

df = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=True, index_col='datetime')

valid_date_ranges = [("2017-01-01 00:00:00.00", "2017-01-03 15:00:00.00"),
                    ("2017-01-04 03:25:00.00", "2017-01-06 22:56:00.00")]
dranges = [pd.date_range(start, end, freq='min') for start, end in valid_date_ranges]
```

Now drop rows that are not found in the date ranges, and build remaining rows in a new `filtered` data frame:

```
filtered = pd.DataFrame()
for drange in dranges:
    filtered = pd.concat([filtered,df.drop(df.index[~df.index.isin(drange)])])

print(filtered)
                        value
datetime                     
2017-01-01 00:00:00      1234
2017-01-01 00:01:00  13241526
2017-01-01 10:02:00    356356
2017-01-01 10:03:00     17435
2017-01-01 10:04:00   5234515
2017-01-01 10:05:00  52452435
2017-01-03 14:59:00    156256
2017-01-03 15:00:00    665654
2017-01-04 03:25:00   4657347
2017-01-04 03:26:00       765
2017-01-04 03:27:00    870089
```

Comment: I want to keep the rows in the date ranges, not drop them.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - note that the output is correct.

Comment: I figured as much